# Delete post after x minutes if user role is

Tags: posts, user-roles

If a user has contributor role (or role of my choice) then delete his posts older than x minutes. How to?

Comment: Subscribers cannot write posts.

Comment: Well it was just a example for a user role. I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple question, but it involves quite some work, so I'll just give you an outline:

First, you need to define a [cron job that runs every minute](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208135/how-to-run-a-function-every-5-minutes) or so. This will allow you to define an action that is run automatically. Beware that this will run only when the site is visited, because otherwise WP is just a bunch of files that sit on your server's hard drive. Now, you have a hook that fires every minute when your site is indeed visited every minute, but less if you get less visits.

Second, you will have to write a function that deletes posts based on the user role of its author. Get all users with a certain role using [`get_users`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/). Feed the result [in a query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) in which you also specify posts older than the X minutes your want. Then loop through all retrieved posts and [delete them](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post).

If you're actually going to do this, you're putting quite a load on your server, so don't expect it to be fast. Doing this max every hour might be a better idea.