# Auto copy value from specific user meta field to another field

Tags: functions, user-meta

I'm looking for synchronizing specific user meta field with another one.

ex: Coping user phone number to woocommerce billing phone.

So the admin can only edit one field and the other updates automaticly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply hook function to sync phone number field as following;

```
<?php

// HOOK ON REGISTERING NEW USER/CUSTOMER
add_action('user_register', 'mm_sync_phone_number' , 20, 1);    

// HOOK ON PERSONAL OPTIONS UPDATE
add_action('personal_options_update', 'mm_sync_phone_number' , 20, 1);

// HOOK ON USER PROFILE UPDATE    
add_action('edit_user_profile_update','mm_sync_phone_number' , 20, 1); 

function mm_sync_phone_number( $user_id ) { 

    // GET PHONE NUMBER FROM OTHER FIELD
    $phone_number = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'meta_key_of_other_phone_field', true );

    // UPDATE PHONE NUMBER IN BILLING PHONE NUMBER FIELD
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone',  $phone_number ); 

}

?>
```

This way every time, whenever admin is going to add or update user/customer from the dashboard, the value of your phone number field will be updated in the other WooCommerce billing phone number field.

Comment: Thank you , It works like a charm 
But Can it be working from cron job to be triggered automatically every specific period?

Comment: Glad to know. Can you share the reason to use cron job over here?

Comment: I'm using ACF to create some user meta field for wallet funds in every user account
So by changing the meta fields in your code , I can display to the user how much he have in his account , by using cron job I can trigger that changes every month :)

Comment: Then you can use wp cron for this and use the same function to trigger in scheduled event. Here is some good expalantion on [how to use scheduled event functionality in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208135/how-to-run-a-function-every-5-minutes#answer-216121)

Comment: Could you please write the final code for this?